# Telegraf issue: [outputs.influxdb] Metric buffer overflow; 3645 metrics have been dropped

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I am trying to extract metrics from vcentre of 1100 VM's using telegraf and storing this data within influxdb. The metrics are being 'successfully' extracted and then displayed on a created dashboard on grafana.

However when I check the status of telegraf it is reported that between 3000 - 11,000 metrics are being dropped. I am unsure if this is an issue with the configuration of telegraf or InfluxDB.

Telegraf vsphere config:

```
# Read metrics from VMware vCenter
 [[inputs.vsphere]]
    ## List of vCenter URLs to be monitored. These three lines must be uncommented
 ## and edited for the plugin to work.
 vcenters = [ "https:/***/sdk" ]
    username = "***"
    password = “***"
 #
 ## VMs
 ## Typical VM metrics (if omitted or empty, all metrics are collected)
 vm_metric_include = [
      "cpu.demand.average",
      "cpu.idle.summation",
      "cpu.latency.average",
      "cpu.readiness.average",
      "cpu.ready.summation",
      "cpu.run.summation",
      "cpu.usagemhz.average",
      "cpu.used.summation",
      "cpu.wait.summation",
      "mem.active.average",
      "mem.granted.average",
      "mem.latency.average",
      "mem.swapin.average",
      "mem.swapinRate.average",
      "mem.swapout.average",
      "mem.swapoutRate.average",
      "mem.usage.average",
      "mem.vmmemctl.average",
      "net.bytesRx.average",
      "net.bytesTx.average",
      "net.droppedRx.summation",
      "net.droppedTx.summation",
      "net.usage.average",
      "power.power.average",
      "virtualDisk.numberReadAveraged.average",
      "virtualDisk.numberWriteAveraged.average",
      "virtualDisk.read.average",
      "virtualDisk.readOIO.latest",
      "virtualDisk.throughput.usage.average",
      "virtualDisk.totalReadLatency.average",
      "virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency.average",
      "virtualDisk.write.average",
      "virtualDisk.writeOIO.latest",
      "sys.uptime.latest",
    ]
 # vm_metric_exclude = [] ## Nothing is excluded by default
 # vm_instances = true ## true by default
 #
 ## Hosts
 ## Typical host metrics (if omitted or empty, all metrics are collected)
 host_metric_include = [
      "cpu.coreUtilization.average",
      "cpu.costop.summation",
      "cpu.demand.average",
      "cpu.idle.summation",
      "cpu.latency.average",
      "cpu.readiness.average",
      "cpu.ready.summation",
      "cpu.swapwait.summation",
      "cpu.usage.average",
      "cpu.usagemhz.average",
      "cpu.used.summation",
      "cpu.utilization.average",
      "cpu.wait.summation",
      "disk.deviceReadLatency.average",
      "disk.deviceWriteLatency.average",
      "disk.kernelReadLatency.average",
      "disk.kernelWriteLatency.average",
      "disk.numberReadAveraged.average",
      "disk.numberWriteAveraged.average",
      "disk.read.average",
      "disk.totalReadLatency.average",
      "disk.totalWriteLatency.average",
      "disk.write.average",
      "mem.active.average",
      "mem.latency.average",
      "mem.state.latest",
      "mem.swapin.average",
      "mem.swapinRate.average",
      "mem.swapout.average",
      "mem.swapoutRate.average",
      "mem.totalCapacity.average",
      "mem.usage.average",
      "mem.vmmemctl.average",
      "net.bytesRx.average",
      "net.bytesTx.average",
      "net.droppedRx.summation", 
      "net.errorsTx.summation",
      "net.usage.average",
      "power.power.average",
      "storageAdapter.numberReadAveraged.average",
      "storageAdapter.numberWriteAveraged.average",
      "storageAdapter.read.average",
      "storageAdapter.write.average",
      "sys.uptime.latest",
    ]
 # host_metric_exclude = [] ## Nothing excluded by default
 # host_instances = true ## true by default
 #
 ## Clusters
 cluster_metric_include = [] ## if omitted or empty, all metrics are collected
 cluster_metric_exclude = [] ## Nothing excluded by default
 # cluster_instances = false ## false by default
 #
 ## Datastores
 datastore_metric_include = [] ## if omitted or empty, all metrics are collected
 # datastore_metric_exclude = [] ## Nothing excluded by default
 # datastore_instances = false ## false by default for Datastores only
 #
 ## Datacenters
 datacenter_metric_include = [] ## if omitted or empty, all metrics are collected
# datacenter_metric_exclude = [ "*" ] ## Datacenters are not collected by default.
 # datacenter_instances = false ## false by default for Datastores only
 #

   ## Plugin Settings
   ## separator character to use for measurement and field names (default: "_")
   # separator = "_"

   ## number of objects to retrieve per query for realtime resources (vms and hosts)
   ## set to 64 for vCenter 5.5 and 6.0 (default: 256)
   # max_query_objects = 256

   ## number of metrics to retrieve per query for non-realtime resources (clusters and datastores)
   ## set to 64 for vCenter 5.5 and 6.0 (default: 256)
   # max_query_metrics = 256

   ## number of go routines to use for collection and discovery of objects and metrics
   # collect_concurrency = 1
   # discover_concurrency = 1

   ## whether or not to force discovery of new objects on initial gather call before collecting metrics
   ## when true for large environments this may cause errors for time elapsed while collecting metrics
   ## when false (default) the first collection cycle may result in no or limited metrics while objects are discov$
   # force_discover_on_init = false

   ## the interval before (re)discovering objects subject to metrics collection (default: 300s)
   # object_discovery_interval = "300s"

   ## timeout applies to any of the api request made to vcenter
   timeout = "180s"

   ## When set to true, all samples are sent as integers. This makes the output
   ## data types backwards compatible with Telegraf 1.9 or lower. Normally all
   ## samples from vCenter, with the exception of percentages, are integer
   ## values, but under some conditions, some averaging takes place internally in
   ## the plugin. Setting this flag to "false" will send values as floats to
   ## preserve the full precision when averaging takes place.
   # use_int_samples = true

   ## Custom attributes from vCenter can be very useful for queries in order to slice the
   ## metrics along different dimension and for forming ad-hoc relationships. They are disabled
   ## by default, since they can add a considerable amount of tags to the resulting metrics. To
   ## enable, simply set custom_attribute_exlude to [] (empty set) and use custom_attribute_include
   ## to select the attributes you want to include.
   # custom_attribute_include = []
   # custom_attribute_exclude = ["*"]

   ## Optional SSL Config
   # ssl_ca = "/path/to/cafile"
   # ssl_cert = "/path/to/certfile"
   # ssl_key = "/path/to/keyfile"
   ## Use SSL but skip chain & host verification
   insecure_skip_verify = true
```

Telegraf agent config

```
# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
  ## Default data collection interval for all inputs
  interval = "180s"
  ## Rounds collection interval to 'interval'
  ## ie, if interval="10s" then always collect on :00, :10, :20, etc.
  round_interval = true

  ## Telegraf will send metrics to outputs in batches of at most
  ## metric_batch_size metrics.
  ## This controls the size of writes that Telegraf sends to output plugins.
  metric_batch_size = 1000

  ## Maximum number of unwritten metrics per output.
  metric_buffer_limit = 1000

  ## Collection jitter is used to jitter the collection by a random amount.
  ## Each plugin will sleep for a random time within jitter before collecting.
  ## This can be used to avoid many plugins querying things like sysfs at the
  ## same time, which can have a measurable effect on the system.
  collection_jitter = "0s"

  ## Default flushing interval for all outputs. Maximum flush_interval will be
  ## flush_interval + flush_jitter
  flush_interval = "10s"
  ## Jitter the flush interval by a random amount. This is primarily to avoid
  ## large write spikes for users running a large number of telegraf instances.
  ## ie, a jitter of 5s and interval 10s means flushes will happen every 10- 15s
  flush_jitter = "0s"

  ## By default or when set to "0s", precision will be set to the same
  ## timestamp order as the collection interval, with the maximum being 1s.
  ##   ie, when interval = "10s", precision will be "1s"

  ## Precision will NOT be used for service inputs. It is up to each individual
  ## service input to set the timestamp at the appropriate precision.
  ## Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s".
  precision = ""

  ## Log at debug level.
  # debug = false
  ## Log only error level messages.
  # quiet = false

  ## Log file name, the empty string means to log to stderr.
  # logfile = ""

  ## The logfile will be rotated after the time interval specified.  When set
  ## to 0 no time based rotation is performed.
  # logfile_rotation_interval = "0d"

  ## The logfile will be rotated when it becomes larger than the specified
  ## size.  When set to 0 no size based rotation is performed.
  # logfile_rotation_max_size = "0MB"

  ## Maximum number of rotated archives to keep, any older logs are deleted.
  ## If set to -1, no archives are removed.
  # logfile_rotation_max_archives = 5

  ## Override default hostname, if empty use os.Hostname()
  hostname = ""
  ## If set to true, do no set the "host" tag in the telegraf agent.
  omit_hostname = false
```

Telegraf influxDB plugin config

```
# Configuration for sending metrics to InfluxDB
[[outputs.influxdb]]
    urls = ["http://***********"]
    database = "vmware"
    timeout = "0s"
```

I am recieving the following error when running systemctl status -l telegraf:

> [outputs.influxdb] Metric buffer overflow; 3645 metrics have been
>   dropped

continuously with varying number of metrics that have been dropped

I also recieve this error which could be a cause or highlight another issue:

> [agent] input "inputs.vsphere" did not complete within its interval

Unsure where the problem lies

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here, and both are quite vocal.

### `inputs.vsphere`

> [agent] input "inputs.vsphere" did not complete within its interval

You run `inputs.vsphere` with an interval which is smaller than the time it takes the plugin to collect the data. You might want to dig into [running several collectors concurrently](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/vsphere#collection-and-discovery-concurrency) to speed up the collection. If that does not help on its own, you need to find the sweet spot between concurrency and increasing the [collection interval](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#intervals).

Do not be afraid to do so. From my experience, people *vastly* overestimate the granularity they actually need. I have seen deployments where the interval was changed from 10s to several minutes. Note that you can [set the interval per input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#input-plugins).

### `outputs.influxdb`

> [outputs.influxdb] Metric buffer overflow; 3645 metrics have been dropped

You collect more datapoints than your buffer is able to hold. Simply increase `metric_buffer_limit` by the maximum number of measurements dropped (plus a good measure just to be on the safe side). As with the `interval`, you can do this either either agent-wide (the value then applies to *each* output) or just for `outputs.influxdb`.